# What is the practice for loading native libraries in Websphere Liberty?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, websphere-liberty

I am installing multiple applications under Websphere Liberty in Linux.  Each application needs to reference the same shared library, which loads a native driver; the library must be loaded into its own classloader.

In prior Websphere (8+) versions, it was very simple to use the UI to configure a library in this fashion: set the scope, give it a name, identify the jars on the classpath, provide the native library path, then check off "use an isolated class loader".  It is different for Liberty.

**What is the practice for doing similar under Websphere Liberty?**

Assume the following:

classpaths:

```
/usr/acc/lib/jars/firstjar-1.0.jar
/usr/acc/lib/jars/secondjar-1.0.jar
/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/thirdjar-1.0.jar
```

native driver:

```
/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/driver.so
```

[According to IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html):

1. for a native driver, I just list it alongside the JAR files in a file tag
2. for a contained classloader, I need to reference it as a "commonLibraryRef".

This means the following *should be* correct:

```
<library id="MyLibrary">
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/jars/firstjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/jars/secondjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/thirdjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/driver.so"/>
</library>

<application id="applicationWAR" location="application.war" name="applicationName" type=”war” autoStart="true">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="MyLibrary"/> 
<application/>
```

**Is that valid, or do I need to add `-Djava.library.path=/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty` to the `jvm.options` file?**

At the time this is being asked, access to the Liberty instance is restricted, so design of the apps.xml is through speculation, requiring this question.

Comment: It matches the manual, does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is correct; the library declaration in `apps.xml` should be maintained above any application declarations.  Updating `jvm.options` is not necessary.  A short-hand is also acceptable using `fileset`, and an application can reference multiple libraries, comma-delimited; demonstrated as follows:

```
<!-- library from above question -->
<library id="MyLibrary">
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/jars/firstjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/jars/secondjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/thirdjar-1.0.jar"/>
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/3rdparty/driver.so"/>
</library>

<!-- short-hand using fileset -->
<library id="AnotherLib">
    <fileset dir="/usr/acc/lib/2ndparty/" includes="*.jar" />
    <file name="/usr/acc/lib/2ndparty/driver.so" />
</library>

<!-- short-hand using fileset and no .so file; includes can be *.* -->
<library id="ThirdLib">
    <fileset dir="/usr/acc/lib/3/" includes="*.jar" />
</library>

<application id="applicationWAR" location="application.war" name="applicationName" type=”war” autoStart="true">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="MyLibrary,AnotherLib,ThirdLib"/> 
<application/>
```